# can not use sorted index in join query

Tags: ignite

I have a query:

```
SELECT pr."productId" FROM "ProductRecord" pr
INNER JOIN "ProductCategory" pc on pr."productId" = pc."productId"
WHERE pc."category" = ? AND pc."language" = ?
ORDER BY pr."dailyRock" DESC `
```

There is a descending ordered index on field dailyRock but since productId index is used on join the sorted index can not be used and everytime the aggregated result is needed to be sorted.

Can I force ignite to use both productId index and dailyRock index of ProductRecord table in the query above?

Answer (score 0):

No, only one index per table may be used in each query.

You can try creating a composite index `(dailyRock, productId)` or `(productId, dailyRock)` although I'm not sure it'll help to avoid the sorting.